# Run nexus in kubernetes cluster using helm

Tags: nexus, kubernetes-helm, google-kubernetes-engine

There is a helm chart for nexus: https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/sonatype-nexus

I installed it like using helm:

```
helm install stable/sonatype-nexus --name=nexus
```

But it didn't work because of nexus-proxy. There is logs for nexus-proxy container:

> [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0]
>   [io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase] Unexpected exception in
>   route

So, i started to google and found that post:
https://github.com/travelaudience/nexus-proxy/issues/4

There we no answer except this:

> I encountered this error. Using imageTag=2.2.0 fixed the problem for
>   me.

So i deleted nexus release and installed that chart like so:

```
helm install stable/sonatype-nexus --name=nexus -f nexus.yml
```

> nexus.yml is this file with replaced value of nexus-proxy image tag
>   https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/sonatype-nexus/values.yaml

Now, when i hit http://localhost:8080/ i get this:

> Invalid host. To browse Nexus, click here/. To use the Docker
>   registry, point your client at .

Tadaaam, what i did wrong? 
I try to install this chart in my kubernetes on mac. I haven't succeed in installing this chart on GKE

Answer (score 8):

I have met the same issue with you (in stable/sonatype-nexus-1.10.0) and I have tried to solve that. I guess your problem is due to docker images like quay.io/travelaudience/docker-nexus-proxy. You can see configuration in values.yaml like

```
nexusProxy:
  imageName: quay.io/travelaudience/docker-nexus-proxy
  imageTag: 2.3.0
  imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  port: 8080
  env:
    nexusDockerHost: 127.0.0.1
    nexusHttpHost: 127.0.0.1
    enforceHttps: false
    cloudIamAuthEnabled: false
```

By default, nexusDockerHost and nexusHttpHost is left blank, so the proxy will deny your access to nexus. to allow access nexus via docker-nexus-proxy. In my case, after I have added 127.0.0.1 to nexusDockerHost/nexusHttpHost, I could access nexus ui from the chart's nodeport configuration.

Comment: I added `127.0.0.1` it didn't work, after that, I added my server IP and it works now. Thanks.

Comment: @Saman could you please advise which server IP you added which had worked? I also tried with 127.0.0.1 and it didn't work. Server IP mean, when we do ```kubectl get svc``` and the IP we get as loadbalancer service ip, is that the one ? Thanks.

Comment: @JaydeepSoni, Sorry for the late answer, I didn't see it. I've put the kubemaster IP address in which nexus was running on one pod/port of it. I hope helps.

Comment: I modified the Values yaml to add 127.0.0.1 for dockerHost/httpHost env vars. I am seeing this error on installing the chart.Error: Ingress.extensions "nexus-chart-1-sonatype-nexus" is invalid: [spec.rules[0].host: Invalid value: "127.0.0.1": must be a DNS name, not an IP address, spec.rules[1].host: Invalid value: "127.0.0.1": must be a DNS name, not an IP address]

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me! It created another ReplicaSet and I had to delete the original one in order to avoid a healthcheck failure in the new pod, but then it worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this with following change, this seems to be port issue, I have deployed on AWS EKS private

```
nexusProxy:
  enabled: true
  # svcName: proxy-svc
  imageName: quay.io/travelaudience/docker-nexus-proxy
  imageTag: 2.6.0
  imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  port: 8080
  targetPort: 8080
```

change

```
nexusProxy:
  enabled: true
  # svcName: proxy-svc
  imageName: quay.io/travelaudience/docker-nexus-proxy
  imageTag: 2.6.0
  imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  port: 8080
  targetPort: 8081
```

Only change the port from 8080 to 8081

Answer (score 0):

For testing purposes following configuration can be used on GKE via port forwarding.

In order to use on production (with ingress), you should use real host names.

```
ingress:
  enabled: false
  ...

nexusProxy:
  ...
  env:
    nexusDockerHost: 127.0.0.1
    nexusHttpHost: 127.0.0.1
  ...
```